# Deploying a polymer project to app engine/java standard of flex environments

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, jetty

I'm looking for instructions [similar to these (python)](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/toolbox/deploy#deploy-to-a-server) on how to deploy a polymer project to app engine that uses java standard or, preferably, flexible environment.  I don't fully understand how a polymer project can be integrated with Jetty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the key here is [to integrate static content](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/serving-static-files) into my application.  There is even no need to add web.xml:

> If you do not specify a web.xml, a default is used that maps
>   everything to the default servlet.

The article even talks about alternatives to serving directly from the application to reduce the costs.